# pandas out of bounds nanosecond timestamp after offset rollforward plus adding a month offset

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, datetimeoffset

I am confused how pandas blew out of bounds for datetime objects with these lines:

```
import pandas as pd
BOMoffset = pd.tseries.offsets.MonthBegin()
# here some code sets the all_treatments dataframe and the newrowix, micolix, mocolix counters
all_treatments.iloc[newrowix,micolix] = BOMoffset.rollforward(all_treatments.iloc[i,micolix] + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months = x))
all_treatments.iloc[newrowix,mocolix] = BOMoffset.rollforward(all_treatments.iloc[newrowix,micolix]+ pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months = 1))
```

Here `all_treatments.iloc[i,micolix]` is a datetime set by `pd.to_datetime(all_treatments['INDATUMA'], errors='coerce',format='%Y%m%d')`, and `INDATUMA` is date information in the format `20070125`.

This logic seems to work on mock data (no errors, dates make sense), so at the moment I cannot reproduce while it fails in my entire data with the following error:

```
pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 2262-05-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: [create a minimal but *complete* code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I managed to fix it by :

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the timespan that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years

```
In [54]: pd.Timestamp.min
Out[54]: Timestamp('1677-09-22 00:12:43.145225')

In [55]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[55]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

And your value is out of this range 2262-05-01 00:00:00 and hence the outofbounds error

Straight out of: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations

**Workaround:**

This will force the dates which are outside the bounds to ***NaT***

`pd.to_datetime(date_col_to_force, errors = 'coerce')`

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have a date index that goes beyond that range?

Comment: @mac13k see [this](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob)...

Comment: I knew about that, thanks. The problem is that you can have the index made of the period range that goes beyond the timestamp limits and it's fine until you actually try to use the individual values from that index - then you will either get errors or incorrect dates.

Comment: @jetpackdata how can we fix this when converting to TimeDate? it seems like a cath20. like how to compare an input before converting it. there should be a way NaT anything out of range?

Comment: Is there a workaround for dates that extend beyond the max limit?  I have a np.where if ['date'] > today, use other col.  Someone fat fingered 3012 instead of 2012 and errors out the equation.

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland This must help. http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob

Comment: Link has changed: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits

Comment: But all my dates are before 1600 should I put it all to NaT? This is not a good solution in my case.

Answer (score 69):

Setting the `errors` parameter in `pd.to_datetime` to `'coerce'` causes replacement of out of bounds values with `NaT`. Quoting the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT

E.g.:

```python
datetime_variable = pd.to_datetime(datetime_variable, errors = 'coerce')
```

This does not fix the data (obviously), but still allows processing the non-NaT data points.

Comment: This is not recommended if we actually want to consider the value rather blindly converting to NaT

Comment: @rams And where have I claimed otherwise?

Comment: hi @pawel: hi, I didn't mean you did claim otherwise,  I just meant if we specify errors='ignore' rather 'coerce' we can keep track / retain the original error value for reference.

Answer (score 20):

The reason you are seeing this error message
**"OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3000-12-23 00:00:00"** is because pandas timestamp data type stores date in nanosecond resolution([from the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits)).

Which means the date values have to be in the range

```
pd.Timestamp.min(1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225) and

pd.Timestamp.max(2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807)
```

Even if you only want the date with resolution of seconds or microseconds, pandas will still store it internally in nanoseconds. There is no option in pandas to store a timestamp outside of the above mentioned range.

This is surprising because databases like sql server and libraries like numpy allows to store date beyond this range. Also maximum of 64 bits are used in most of the cases to store the date.

But here is the difference.
**SQL server** stores date in nanosecond resolution but only up to a accuracy of 100 ns(as opposed to 1 ns in pandas). Since the space is limited(64 bits), its a matter of range vs accuracy. With pandas timestamp we have higher accuracy but lower date range.

**In case of numpy** (pandas is built on top of numpy) datetime64 data type,

- if the date falls in the above mentioned [range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits) you    can store
  it in nanoseconds which is similar to pandas.
- OR you can give up the nanosecond resolution and go with
  microseconds which will give you a much larger range. This is something that is missing in pandas timestamp type.

However if you choose to store in nanoseconds and the date is outside the range then numpy will automatically wrap around this date and you might get unexpected results (*referenced below in the 4th solution*).

```
np.datetime64("3000-06-19T08:17:14.073456178", dtype="datetime64[ns]")
> numpy.datetime64('1831-05-11T09:08:06.654352946')
```

**Now with pandas we have below options,**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Sam'], 'dob': ['3000-06-19T08:17:14', '2000-06-19T21:17:14']}
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**1)If you are ok with losing the data which is out of range then simply use below param to convert out of range date to NaT(not a time).**

```
my_df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['dob'], errors = 'coerce')
```

[image]

**2)If you dont want to lose the data then you can convert the values into a python datetime type.** Here the column "dob" is of type pandas object but the individual value will be of type python datetime. However doing this we will lose the benefit of vectorized functions.

```
import datetime as dt
my_df['dob'] = my_df['dob'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') if type(x)==str else pd.NaT)
print(type(my_df.iloc[0][1]))
> <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

[image]

**3)Another option is to use numpy instead of pandas series if possible.** In case of pandas dataframe, you can convert a series(or column in a df) to numpy array. Process the data separately and then join it back to the dataframe.

**4)we can also use pandas timespans as suggested in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans)**. Do checkout the difference b/w timestamp and period before using this data type. Date range and frequency here works similar to numpy(*mentioned above in the numpy section*).

```
my_df['dob'] = my_df['dob'].apply(lambda x: pd.Period(x, freq='ms'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can try with strptime() in datetime library along with lambda expression to convert text to date values in a series object:

***Example:***

```
df['F'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S') if type(x)==str else np.NaN)
```

Comment: This is perfect - exactly what I needed to solve the nanoseconds out of bounds problem without losing underlying data.

Answer (score 3):

None of above are so good, because it will delete your data. But, you can only mantain and edit your conversion:

```
# convertin from epoch to datatime mantainig the nanoseconds timestamp
xbarout= pd.to_datetime(xbarout.iloc[:,0],unit='ns')
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that arrived here from using `pd.read_sql_query()` with the `dtype` param with datetime values and got this
`OutOfBoundsDatetime` error, you can fix this issue using the parameter `parse_dates` to set errors='coerce' for the date column. E.g:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn,  dtype={'date_col': 'datetime64'), parse_dates={'date_col': {'errors': 'coerce'}}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a current version of Pandas. I was having this issue while trying to upload a table into BigQuery (CloudShell downloads a 1.5.* by default) while reading a parquet file with Pandas and using engine= 'pyarrow':

```
df = pd.read_parquet(path, engine='pyarrow')
```

My solution was to upgrade Pandas package version to 2.0.3 and change the engine to 'fastparquet' (which gave me a different error with the older Pandas version):

```
df = pd.read_parquet(path, engine='fastparquet')
```