# Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a variable ['date_hiring'] in Googlespeedsheet in format like

```
16.01.2016
```

I import it in Python, the variable has an object type. I try to convert to datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
data['date_hiring'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_hiring'])
```

and i get

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 16-01-06 00:00:00
```

i know from this [pandas out of bounds nanosecond timestamp after offset rollforward plus adding a month offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a) that

> Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the
>   timespan that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to
>   approximately 584 years

but in original data in the Googlespeedsheet i have no data like '16.01.06'

Just like '16.06.2006'

So the problem is in converting

How to improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), the *dayfirst* field defaults to false:

> dayfirst : boolean, default False

So it must have decided that there was a malformed date there and tried to interpret it as a time-of-day.

But even then it probably didn't think that 16 point anything could be hours or minutes, so it tried to convert it as seconds.  But there is a extra decimal point so it gave up and said I don't like the fractional seconds.   (Or something like that.)

I think you can fix it by giving an explicit format string or at least setting *dayfirst*.