# Type error, 'method' object is not subscriptable while iteratig

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I am working with huge data frame:

```
reader = pd.read_csv("D:/...path.../test.csv", names=["id_easy","ordinal", "latitude", "longitude","epoch",'weekday'], 
                 parse_dates=['epoch'], chunksize=n_rows, error_bad_lines=False)

day_names = (('0:00', '1:00'),('1:00', '2:00'),('2:00', '3:00'),('3:00', '4:00'),('4:00', '5:00'),('5:00', '6:00'),
             ('6:00', '7:00'),('7:00', '8:00'),('8:00', '9:00'),('9:00', '10:00'),('10:00', '11:00'),('11:00', '12:00'),
             ('12:00', '13:00'),('13:00', '14:00'),('14:00', '15:00'),('15:00', '16:00'),('16:00', '17:00'),('17:00', '18:00'),
             ('18:00', '19:00'),('19:00', '20:00'),('20:00', '21:00'),('21:00', '22:00'),('22:00', '23:00'),('23:00', '00:00'))

for df in reader: 
    if not df.empty: 
        df['epoch'] = pd.to_datetime(df.epoch,unit = 's')
        df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.epoch)
        for day in day_names: 
            day_df = df.between_time[day] # ERROR IS HERE
            if not day_df.empty:
                day_df.to_csv(f'{day}.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a')
```

---

> TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

---

Desired output is 24 .csv files like: final1,final2,...,final24

---

## Sample data:

```
e35f652a    68  11.9125 3.7432  1465084811  Sunday
e35f652a    69  11.8992 3.7412  1465084870  Sunday
e35f652a    70  11.8866 3.7342  1465084930  Sunday
e35f652a    71  11.8755 3.7321  1465084990  Sunday
e35f652a    72  11.8675 3.7247  1465085050  Sunday
```

---

Somehow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157958/how-to-reduce-the-memory-usage-and-speed-up-the-code) question is more or less similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `[]` used for indexing to `()` because [`DataFrame.between_time()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) and select first and second value of tuple by indexing:

```
for day in day_names: 
    day_df = df.between_time(day[0], day[1])
```

Or change loop for unpack tuples:

```
for s, e in day_names: 
    day_df = df.between_time(s, e)
```

Comment: `TypeError: between_time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end_time'` this happened

Comment: I guess it takes the ('0:00', '1:00') like only starting time, yes?

Comment: Almost perfect! In last line I get error while saving the new file `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "('1:00', '2:00').csv"`

Comment: @Mamed - then decide if `day_df.to_csv(f'{day[0]}.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a')` or `day_df.to_csv(f'{day[1]}.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a')`

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1:00.csv'`

Comment: @Mamed - How are filenames?

Comment: I want to get 24 csv files like: final1,final2,final3,...,final24

Comment: @Mamed - It is not valid filename, because `:`

Comment: @Mamed  try `day_df.to_csv(f'{day[0].replace(":","_")}.csv', index=False, header=False, mode='a')`