# Quickest Pandas Value Updating Method?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, time

I'm going through over 1 million patent applications and have to fix the dates, in addition to other things that I will work on later. I'm reading the file into a Pandas data frame, then running the following function:

```
def date_change():
        new_dates = {'m/y': []}
        for i, row in apps.iterrows():
                try:
                        d = row['date'].rsplit('/')
                        new_dates['m/y'].append('{}/19{}'.format(d[0], d[2]))
                except Exception as e:
                        print('{}   {}\n{}\n{}'.format(i, e, row, d))
                        new_dates['m/y'].append(np.nan)
        apps.join(pd.DataFrame(new_dates))
        apps.drop('date')
```

Is there a quicker way of executing this? Is Pandas even the correct library to be using with a dataset this large? I've been told PySpark is good for big data, but how much will it improve the speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems like you are using a string to represent data instead of a date time object.
I'd suggest to do something like

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

So you don't need to iterate at all, as that function operate on the whole column.
And then, you might want to check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067704/how-to-change-the-datetime-format-in-pandas) which uses [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to format your column appropriately.

If you could show input and expected output, I could add the full solution here.

Besides, 1 million rows should typically be manageable for pandas (depending on the number of columns of course)

Comment: Never used to_datetime before, thanks for bringing it to my attention! Input: 2/21/44, Output: 2/21/1944. For this there are only 6 columns, but that's good to know.

Comment: Update: Worked well, but it interpreted a bunch of the values as being from the 20 aughts instead of 19 aughts (all data is from 20th century).

Comment: You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a), but I'm unsure if this will help in a straight forward way: