# A script to correct corrupted date values

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

my dataframe contains numerous incorrect datetime values that have been fat-fingered in by the people who entered those data.  The errors are mostly 2019-11-12 was entered at 0019-12-12 and 2018 entered as 0018.  There are so many of them, so I want came up with a script to correct them en mass. I used the following code:

```
df['A'].loc[df.A.dt.year<100]=df.A.dt.year+2000
```

Basically, I want tell python to detect any of the years less than 100 then add 2000 to the year.  However, I am getting error :"Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 19-11-19 00:00:00"  Is there any solution to my problem?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the limitations of timestamps : see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a) about *out of bounds nanosecond timestamp*.

Therefore, I suggest correcting the column as a string before turning it into a datetime column, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["2019-10-04", "0019-04-02", "0018-06-08", "2018-07-08"]})

# I look for every date starting with zero and another number and replace by 20
r = re.compile(r"^0[0-9]{1}")
df["A"] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: r.sub('20', x))
# then I transform to datetime
df["A"] = pd.to_datetime(df["A"], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df
```

Here is the result

```
          A
0 2019-10-04
1 2019-04-02
2 2018-06-08
3 2018-07-08
```

You need to make sure that you can only have dates in `20XX` (where X is any number) and not dates in `19XX` or other before applying this.

Comment: I am getting an error on df["A"] = df["A"].apply(lambda x: r.sub('20', x)).  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.  I guess it's because column "A" is datetime to begin with?

Comment: Try transforming  it to a string before applying the `sub` with `df["A"] = df["A"].astype(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to export to csv. Then make the changes and import again.

```
    df.to_csv('path/csvfile.csv')

    text = open("path/csvfile.csv", "r")
    text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
        .replace("0019-", "2019-")
    x = open("path/newcsv.csv","w")
    x.writelines(text)
    x.close()

    df_new = pd.read_csv("path/newcsv.csv")
```