# time data '193003' does not match format '%y-%m' (match)

Tags: python, data-analysis, valueerror

I have this problem with converting string to datetime in python. but it didn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hZVj.png)

Comment: Please post you code and error output as text. Screenshots of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For 193003, The format should be

```py
# change data type to str if not already the case
cus_data["TYMD"] = cus_data["TYMD"].astype(str)
cus_data["TYMD"] = cus_data["TYMD"].str[:4] + "-" + cus_data["TYMD"].str[4:]
```

or

```py
cus_data["TYMD"] = cus_data["TYMD"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:4] + "-" + str(x)[4:])
```

Comment: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-01 00:00:00      what's wrong?:(

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: I just want to convert a string series to a date type. And it wants to be expressed like '1930-03'.

Comment: you shold use other string method as the date is not a complete date. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

`%y` is for short year. Ex, 2018 will be represented as 18, and `%Y` is for long year. In your case, your format is `%y-%m`, so your format should be `30-03`. If you want the full year, `%Y%m` will work.

Comment: OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-01 00:00:00 what's wrong?:(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a refer to this