# Python - Converting column with different dates format not working beyond 3000 using pandas to_datetime()

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I want to convert the date column in dataframe with different formats to python datetime. The function `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)` is working only till year 3000.

Please find below the example
import pandas as pd

```
#Create the pandas DataFrame
data = [['A', '2021-08-08'], ['B', '2021/08/08'], ['C', '3031-08-08']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Date'])
```

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-08-08 |
| B | 2021/08/08 |
| C | 3031-08-08 |

1. pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # giving errors

`OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3031-08-08 00:00:00`

2. pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors = 'coerce') # converting year beyond 3000 to NaT

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-08-08 |
| B | 2021-08-08 |
| C | NaT |

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, pandas timestamp doesn't support dates past 2262-04-11 23:47:16.
[pandas.Timestamp.max](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.max.html)

Comment: Thanks, is there any alternate way to achieve the solution? Could have used the mapping if only one date format was there however it is not the case.

Comment: I think your best bet is to embed a different type of object in the timeseries, so instead of using pandas timestamps, a decent bet would be to use standard datetimes., like shown in this answer from the suggested has-an-answer-already tag:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63671618/1024114

`df['F'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S') if type(x)==str else np.NaN)
`