# I have str which includes a date that I'm trying to extract

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a string which is similar to this

> 02032021..........SW01SW05..........

I have already extracted everything I need from it except for the date which is the first block of digits. the dates are between Jan 21 and YTD.

I used this code to get only the digits `df.loc[x, "Date Worked"] = df["Worked In Cost Number"].str.slice(0,10).astype(str)` x is subset which contains strings with the same format.

and then I tried to convert it to date `df["Date Worked"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date Worked"].str.slice(0,2) + df["Date Worked"].str.slice(2,4)+  df["Date Worked"].str.slice(4,8), format = '%m%d%Y')`

but when i do that i get this error

> OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3202-03-12 00:00:00

I the issue is that when I slice it, it turns into a float and dismisses the leading zero.

Comment: `df["Date Worked"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Worked In Cost Number"].str[:8], format='%m%d%Y')`

Comment: Maybe your column contains string like this:
"03123202..........SW01SW05.........." 
and that is the reason why you can't convert it to date?
Here is the similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can handle those digits, with a mock "date" string. You'll have to separate the date from the string you provided to make this work, probably with slicing as you have already done.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
example_date = "02032021"

print(datetime.strptime(example_date, "%m%d%Y"))
```

Output:

```
2021-02-03 00:00:00
```