# Get unique years from a date column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python

I have a date column in my DataFrame say `df_dob` and it looks like -

| id | DOB |
| --- | --- |
| 23312 | 31-12-9999 |
| 1482 | 31-12-9999 |
| 807 | #VALUE! |
| 2201 | 06-12-1925 |
| 653 | 01/01/1855 |
| 108 | 01/01/1855 |
| 768 | 1967-02-20 |

What I want to print is a list of unique years like - `['9999', '1925', '1855', '1967']

basically through this list I just wanted to check whether there is some unwanted year is present or not.
I have tried(pasted my code below) but getting `ValueError: time data 01/01/1855 doesn't match format specified` and could not resolve it.

```
df_dob['DOB'] = df_dob['DOB'].replace('01/01/1855 00:00:00', '1855-01-01')
df_dob['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dob.DOB, format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_dob['DOB'] = df_dob['DOB'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(np.unique(df_dob['DOB']))
# print(list(df_dob['DOB'].year.unique()))
```

P.S - when I print `df_dob['DOB']`, I get values like - `1967-02-20 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas' unique for this. And on year only.

So try:

```
print(df['DOB'].dt.year.unique())
```

Also, you don't need to stringify your time. Alse, you don't need to replace anything, pandas is smart enough to do it for you. So you overall code becomes:

```
df_dob['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dob.DOB)    # No need to pass format if there isn't some specific anomoly
print(df['DOB'].dt.year.unique())
```

Edit:

**Another method:**
Since you have outofbounds problem,
Another method you can try is not converting them to datetime, but rather find all the four digit numbers in each column using regex.
So,

```
df['DOB'].str.extract(r'(\d{4})')[0].unique()
```

`[0]` because `unique()` is a function of `pd.series` not a `dataframe`. So taking the first series in the dataframe.

Comment: Hi @Nitish,  I have tried doing but I get `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00`

Comment: I see you have some time with year 9999. Whatsup with that?

Comment: Yes, that is included in the data, it might be 1999, but mistakenly typed 9999, that is the reason I need to print the list of years to check.

Comment: Pandas has a limit to how many years of timespan you can have in a column. Roughly 500 years or so. More details in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a

Comment: Hi @Nitish, thanks for guiding me, so is there any way to filter out my data based on valid dates, so I just wanted to have those rows where there is a valid date

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
df_dob["DOB"] = pd.to_datetime(df_DOB["Date"])

df_dob['YOB'] = df_dob['DOB'].dt.strftime('%Y')
```

Comment: Hi @Nova, I tried but I get - `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 9999-12-31 00:00:00`

Comment: corrected with `df_dob["DOB"] = pd.to_datetime(df_dob["DOB"], errors = 'coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to know is if the resulting values (which you said look like `1967-02-20 00:00:00` are datetimes or not. That's as simple as `df_dob.info()`

If the result says similar to `datetime64[ns]` for the DOB column, you're good. If not you'll need to cast it as a DateTime. You have a couple of different formats so that might be part of your problem. Also, because there're several ways of doing this and it's a separate question, I'm not addressing it.

We going to leverage the speed of sets, plus a bit of pandas, and then convert that back to a list as you wanted the final version to be.

```
years = list({i for i in df['date'].dt.year})
```

And just a side note, you can't use `[]` instead of `list()` as you'll end with a list with a single element that's a set.

That's a list as you indicated. If you want it as a column, you won't get unique values

Nitish's answer will also work but give you something like: `array([9999, 1925, 1855, 1967])`