# convert string to datetime for old years (out of bound problem)

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, timestamp

I am working with dataset of some historical subjects, some of them are in 1500's. I need to convert the datatype of some columns to datetime so I can calculate the difference in days. I tried pandas.to_datetime for converting strings in columns to datetime, but it returned Out of Bound error.

The issue can be reproduced by the following code:

```
datestring = '01-04-1595'
datenew = pd.to_datetime(datestring,format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

and the output error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1595-04-01 00:00:00
```

I learned that the limits of timestamp are min 1677-09-21 and max 2262-04-11, but what would be the workaround for this? The expected timestamp range that will accomodate my dataset is between 1500 to 1900.

I would like to apply the string to datetime conversion for all entries of a column.

Thank you.

Comment: When asking a code related question, the very first tag you should add is for the language that you're using. When asking a database or SQL question, the very first tag you add should be for the specific RDBMS you're using. Please [edit] your post to add the appropriate tag. For more information, see [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas out of bounds nanosecond timestamp after offset rollforward plus adding a month offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888124/pandas-out-of-bounds-nanosecond-timestamp-after-offset-rollforward-plus-adding-a)

Comment: see the linked duplicate: use for example Python's datetime class.

Comment: example of the dataframe ?  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example